# How to get variables from for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to make a for loop, which makes me 1000 objects and places those to a randomly generated spot (x, y). So here is the code. I have been struggling with this many hours and I have also been searching from the net but haven't found out any way to do that. After that loop I try to add those objects into some kind of radar.

Here's the code (so the problem is that I can't figure out how to take variables from the loop and make it appear outside the loop):

```
case "look": {

        System.out.print("You are at: " +px +", " +py);
        System.out.println("");

        StringBuilder objects = new StringBuilder(); //That's something i found out form the net..
        while (objnum>=0){ objnum--;   //Creates randomly 1000objects around the map
        int objid = (int)(Math.random() * 11 + 1);    //int objnum is 1000, told above
        int objx = (int)(Math.random() * 10000 + 1);  
        int objy = (int)(Math.random() * 10000 + 1);}
        board.spawnObject(new BoardObject(objectid, objx, //That's something i found out form the net..
                    objy, objnum));

        for(int x=px-2 ; x< px+3 ; x++ ){ //px=player position
        for(int y=py-2 ; y< py+3 ; y++ ){ //this is how radar is created
        if(objid==1 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=1;}
        else if(objid==2 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=2;}
        else if(objid==3 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=3;} //That's where i need info from the loop..
        else if(objid==4 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=4;}
        else if(objid==5 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=5;}
        else if(objid==6 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=-1;}
        else if(objid==7 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=-2;}
        else if(objid==8 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=-3;}
        else if(objid==9 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=-4;}
        else if(objid==10 && x==objx && y==objy){board[x][y]=-5;}
            if(x==px && y==py){
                board[x][y]=6;}//<- this shows players position on radar
            if(board[x][y]==-1){
                System.out.print("[sto]");
            }else if(board[x][y]==0){
                System.out.print("[___]");//<- This works well..
            }else if(board[x][y]==-2){
                System.out.print("[box]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==-3){
                System.out.print("[ppl]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==-4){
                System.out.print("[pit]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==-5){
                System.out.print("[brk]");
            } //That's how radar shows dots/objects 
            else if(board[x][y]==1){
                System.out.print("[kid]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==2){
                System.out.print("[tre]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==3){
                System.out.print("[pet]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==4){
                System.out.print("[bus]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==5){
                System.out.print("[???]");
            }
            else if(board[x][y]==6){
                System.out.print("[You]");} //<- This works well..
        }
        System.out.println();
    }; }break;
```

Comment: you should really format your code better. if your using eclipse you can hit ctrl - shift - f to format the file. and you can customize your formatter in the eclipse options.

Comment: As i said, i have been doing that for 2months, means that i'm not a professional and i use notpad++.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Collection interface class like Vector for storing objects and then, access them from outside the loop.Follow this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable outside the scope and if a condition is true, than change the value of the variable outside the loop, so:

```
class example {
int number = 0;
.....

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i == 5) {
        number = 5;
    }
}
```

If the condition is true, then number becomes 5, to get this data, you can create getters and setters.

But if you want to store all those 1000 objects in 1 object, i would recommend to use an array(list), so:

```
class Example {
ArrayList<Integer> object = new ArrayList<Integer>();

case.....
object.add(objx)
object.add(objy)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, rly good answer. I think i can make it work now. :)

Comment: hmm.. what should i do to first case of that Array list? :s This is my first time using that kind of command and cmd says: error orphaned case and my ArrayList looks like this (problem is only on the first case):

 ArrayList<Integer> object = new ArrayList<Integer>();{
   case objid == 1:{
   object.add(objnum);
   object.add(objx);
   object.add(objy)
   ;}